# What does the quantum behavior of indivisual in the Particle Swarm Optimization (PSO) algorithm means?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, algorithms

I am not specializing in physics,is it possible to explain; in simplified manner,  what does the ***quantum behavior*** of individuals (particles) in the ***Quantum Particle Swarm Optimization (QPSO) algorithm*** exactly means?

Comment: What have you looked up yourself, is it covered on Wikipedia?  Which part of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization is causing you problems? The more specific you are, the easier it is to answer a question based on a particular point. No offence but **I have read about the quantum behavior in general, but I could not understand it.** is not a good start but I can't see an immediate link between the two areas you are asking about.

Comment: @CountTo10 have you heard about ***Quantum-Particle Swarm Optimization (QPSO)*** algorithm algorithm ?

Comment: I an afraid not, my comment was designed to give you the best chance of an answer, by stressing that other users are more likely to respond by seeing a specific, focused question. The best of luck with your question.